# VBA error object doesn't support this object or method

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub addempty()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim x As Integer

    For i = 3 To 300
        x = 0
        j = i - 1
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = "FX" And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i - 1, 1).Value) Then
            Do While Cells(j, 4).Value <> ""
                x = Cells(j, 4).Value + x
                j = j - 1
            Loop
        End If
        Cells(i, 4).vlue = x
    Next i
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code, where the mistake is?

Comment: Which line errors? You have a typo three lines from the bottom.

Comment: I've checked it - the "vlue" typo is the only problem here.

Comment: @Wujaszkun - I can imagine that `j` might reach zero?

Comment: @SJR It will not because of  `For i = 3 To 300` and  `j = i - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a grammar error here:

`Cells(i, 4).vlue = x` should be

`Cells(i, 4).value = x`

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy